# Python Dash App: Heroku Application Error

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

So I'm building a dash app and using Heroku to host. 
You can view my code here: [My code](https://github.com/CoderHahs/ml-training/tree/master/Projects/covid-app-nogit)

The site can be found here: [covid19-report.herokuapp.com](https://covid19-report.herokuapp.com)
(thought I'd make a covid19 dashboard just to practise data analytics with plotly dash)

Basically I followed the Dash deployment documentation for heroku found here: [Dash Deployment Documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment)

The app runs fine locally, but I'm really not sure why its failing on Heroku.

Below is the error message. It looks like some JSON error, but again it runs fine locally. Some insight into this would help. Thank you!

```
2020-04-18T04:31:17.714587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-18T04:31:27.701650+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-04-18T04:31:27.702418+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:55039 (4)
2020-04-18T04:31:27.702566+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-04-18T04:31:27.708762+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-04-18T04:31:27.785970+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-04-18T04:31:29.269562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266850+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 583, in spawn_worker
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266852+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py"
, line 119, in init_process

2020-04-18T04:31:45.266853+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py"
, line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266853+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266854+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", li
ne 67, in wsgi
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266854+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266855+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
 line 49, in load
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266855+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266855+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
 line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266855+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266856+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 3
58, in import_app
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266856+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266857+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266857+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266859+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266859+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266859+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 42, in <module>
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266860+00:00 app[web.1]: initial_data = pd.DataFrame(r.json())[['Date', 'Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovere
d']].groupby('Date').sum().reset_index()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266860+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line
 898, in json
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266861+00:00 app[web.1]: return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

2020-04-18T04:31:45.266861+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266861+00:00 app[web.1]: return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266862+00:00 app[web.1]: obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_deco
de
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266863+00:00 app[web.1]: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2020-04-18T04:31:45.266871+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.267475+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306244+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306250+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", lin
e 583, in spawn_worker
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306252+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py"
, line 119, in init_process
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306253+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306253+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py"
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306253+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306253+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py"
, line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306253+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306254+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", li
ne 67, in wsgi
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306254+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
 line 49, in load
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306255+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
 line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306256+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306256+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 3

58, in import_app
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306256+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306257+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in im
port_module
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306258+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306258+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306260+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306260+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306260+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 42, in <module>
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306261+00:00 app[web.1]: initial_data = pd.DataFrame(r.json())[['Date', 'Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovere
d']].groupby('Date').sum().reset_index()
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line
 898, in json
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306262+00:00 app[web.1]: return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306262+00:00 app[web.1]: return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306263+00:00 app[web.1]: obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306264+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_deco
de
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306264+00:00 app[web.1]: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2020-04-18T04:31:45.306273+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.307523+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-04-18T04:31:45.664281+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-04-18T04:31:45.664592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 04:31:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-04-18T04:31:45.805719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-04-18T04:38:59.314463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=covid19-repor
t.herokuapp.com request_id=b48e8c2e-9724-47fd-9a55-e786cb0c1508 fwd="209.17.96.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I verified this, and I'm pretty sure that [this line](https://github.com/CoderHahs/ml-training/blob/c4f085fc9a0b95aa9624609667c699584ab2b834/Projects/covid-app-nogit/app.py#L37) is the problem. Maybe not use a ip api, it doesnt work on a hosted computer. Try to use a default initial country

EDIT: you can also try [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-log-client-ip-addresses/6613/2) and once you get the ip of the client try this api https://ipapi.co/ip-address/json

Comment: Yup that was exactly the issue! Wow, you have no clue how long I was frustrated with this. Thank you so much. I'll definitely look into trying to get the ip address the way you suggest in the links